# How do I ignore calendar events if sent to a certain group or from a certain user?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, apple-mail

Is there a way to filter calendar requests that are sent to certain mail groups even if they are marked required, e.g., california@domain.com by making an Outlook 365 server side rule?

I administrate several groups and while I need to see the content, the meeting requests I don't need to see and don't want my calendar being populated with it as they are across the country and thus don't affect me.

The issue is, I still want my corporate calendar synced, I don't want notifications for these meetings, but I do want notifications I would care about.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

We can create an inbox rule to automatically delete these meeting request. Please refer to following Rule Description:

[image]

But we cannot turn off reminders on appointments sent from others in Outlook calendar by using the rules.